# Auto-Merge from staging branch to main every set period of time

Tags: github

Is there a way to auto-merge from staging/dev branch into main every like 6 hours on github?

Let's say I push into staging from a feature/issue branch, then push some more. Though, it only gets auto merged into main in 6 hours intervals for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write a GitHub Action, similar to [`tibdex/auto-update`](https://github.com/tibdex/auto-update) (which is about keeping pull requests with auto-merge enabled up to date with their base branch)

(I did not see any [existing GitHub Action](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions) for your specific use case)

In your case, those are not PR branches, but the idea remains the same.

You can [run a GitHub Action on a schedule](https://jasonet.co/posts/scheduled-actions/), using [`schedule`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule=).